# How to get the LAST element in a list for Ember Acceptance Testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, acceptance-testing

When writing Acceptance tests, does anyone happen to know how one would select the LAST element in a list?  I am testing the act of adding a new record to a list and would like to edit/delete the newly created record in my test.
I've tried to select the newly created record like this....

```
let newRecordLink = find('div.parent-list .list-group-item').last();
click(newRecordLink);
```

Which sorta works.  It pulls the last element, but it busts out of my test and suddenly I'm on the actual page of the app I'm trying to test instead of remain within the test container.

Here is the relevant HBS code:

```
<div class="list-group parent-list">
  {{#each model.owners as |item|}}
    {{#link-to 'client.members.edit-owner' item.id class="list-group-item" id=item.id}}
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
      </h4>
    {{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `{{#link-to}}` helper or a pure `<a href>`?

Comment: I'm using a link-to.  Will post partial template in original question in case that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:last` selector (https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
click('div.parent-list .list-group-item:last')
```

Comment: I tried this originally but could not get it working, still, I can try it again and report my results.

Comment: `:last` selector should work, I suggest you to run the test in the browser and check that `$('div.parent-list .list-group-item:last')` returns something. Maybe there something wrong with `div.parent-list .list-group-item` selector. Have you tried using just `.list-group-item`?

Answer (score 0):

if it is an ember array u can use .get('lastObject')

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too, but I got it to work by using :last-of-type instead of :last